# how to get certain text present in script of website

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to crawl the data of this particular site but the difficult part is the detail I need is present inside the script. I tried using beautifulsoup and selenium but then also I didn't get what I need

> http://www.myntra.com/tops/rare/rare-burgundy-crepe-blouson-top/1437335/buy

The output must be

`Product Details Burgundy woven blouson top with gathers, has a round neck, sleeveless, criss-cross detail on the back Material & Care Crepe Hand-wash cold`

here is the code which I am trying.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
x=urllib.urlopen("http://www.myntra.com/tops/rare/rare-burgundy-crepe-blouson-top/1437335/buy")
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(x, 'html.parser')


for i in soup2.find_all('p',atttrs={'class':'pdp-product-description-content'}):
    print i.text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better do this using regex & json. First you will need to extract the script variable from the page source using **regex**, then load the extracted text into a **json** object, finally your data is stored under the **productDescriptors** key in the final json dict.

```
import re
import json
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

x = urllib.urlopen("http://www.myntra.com/tops/rare/rare-burgundy-crepe-blouson-top/1437335/buy")

soup2 = BeautifulSoup(x, 'html.parser')

product_data = re.findall('({"pdpData".+?)</script>', re.sub('\n', ' ', soup2.prettify()))

product_description = json.loads(product_data[0])['pdpData']['productDescriptors']

print product_description
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'http://www.myntra.com/tops/rare/rare-burgundy-crepe-blouson-top/1437335/buy'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
req = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(req,'html.parser')

producttitle = soup.find('h6',{'class':'pdp-product-description-title'})
productbody = soup.find('p',{'class':'pdp-product-description-content'})

print producttitle.text, productbody.text


matc = soup.findAll('h6',{'class':'pdp-product-description-title'})[1:]
for x in matc:
    print x.text

matd = soup.findAll('p',{'class':'pdp-product-description-content'})[1:]
for y in matd:
    print y.text
```

This will print:

```
Product Details Burgundy woven blouson top with gathers, has a round neck, sleeveless, criss-cross detail on the back
Material & Care
CrepeHand-wash cold
```